# How can I automatically convert all comments in a word 2010 document to footnotes?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, comments, footnote

I started writing comments on some text in word 2010, and I wrote so many that they don't fit on the page.  I want to convert them to footnotes so that they come out well in print.  Is there any way to convert comments to footnotes without making footnotes one at a time?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there's no build-in functionality, but it's an easy task for a VBA macro (which i've found [here](http://www.ms-office-forum.net/forum/showthread.php?t=272281)):

```basic
    Sub comment2footnote()
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Dim oDoc As Document, oComment As Comment
      Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
      For Each oComment In ActiveDocument.Comments
          oDoc.Footnotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope, Text:=oComment.Range.Text
          oComment.Delete
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

This will insert footnotes for each comment, copying the comment's text and removing the comment afterwards.