# Word or LibreOffice/OpenOffice - How to automatically insert footnote text in document body at footnote reference mark?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I have some docx documents that contain a lot of footnotes with usually a short footnote text (e.g. "Richard 2010." or "see section xy"). It's much more convenient to have these in the document body in brackets[] at and in lieu of the footnote reference mark. I don't find a function for this in Word or LibreOffice. I guess I need a macro.

I have seen here [a macro that converts comments into footnotes. It's only ten lines](https://superuser.com/questions/160657/how-can-i-automatically-convert-all-comments-in-a-word-2010-document-to-footnote/). I tried for one night to learn some macro basics and modify some existing macros but failed miserably.

Answer (score 0):

A starting point:

```
Sub bootNoteIntoBody()
Dim bScreenUpdating As Boolean
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oNote As Footnote
Dim rng As Range
Dim strStyleName As String

bScreenUpdating = Application.ScreenUpdating
On Error GoTo finish
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
For Each oNote In ActiveDocument.Footnotes
  ' choose your own maximum length
  If Len(oNote.Range.Text) < 20 Then
    Set rng = oNote.Reference
    With rng
      strStyleName = .Style
      .Text = "[" & cleanup(oNote.Range.Text) & "]"
      .Style = strStyleName
    End With
  End If
Next

finish:
Application.ScreenUpdating = bScreenUpdating

End Sub

Function cleanup(s As String) As String
' replace certain characters by space.
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As String
r = ""
For i = 1 To Len(s)
  Select Case AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
    Case 1 To 31 ' and perhaps others
      r = r & " "
    Case Else
      r = r & Mid(s, i, 1)
  End Select
Next
cleanup = r
End Function
```