# How can i move footnote reference from middle of paragraph to end ? Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, footnote

I turned my comments into footnotes using the following macro by tohuwawohu (very helpful one thanks man) but because of how I had my comments placed it turned out that most of footnote references (the numbers in text 1,2 etc) where in awkward places in the middle of sentence.

Is there a macro or some other way I can move it at the end of sentence/paragraph?

Link and macro:

([How can I automatically convert all comments in a word 2010 document to footnotes?](https://superuser.com/questions/160657/how-can-i-automatically-convert-all-comments-in-a-word-2010-document-to-footnote))

```
Sub comment2footnote()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Dim oDoc As Document, oComment As Comment
  Set oDoc = ActiveDocument
  For Each oComment In ActiveDocument.Comments
      oDoc.Footnotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope, Text:=oComment.Range.Text
      oComment.Delete
  Next
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

(assuming for this example that comment is within single paragraph/sentence) Edit the Range in the first line of code in your For loop.

To put at end of paragraph that the comment is in:

```
oDoc.Footnotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope.Paragraphs(1).Range, Text:=oComment.Range.Text
```

To put at end of sentence - if you use 2 spaces after full stop, then this will leave a space between the full stop and the footnote reference.  You could add a second .Previous at end (ie .Last.Previous.Previous) but then if your sentence is at the end of a paragraph, moving back 2 characters may put the footnote before the full stop:

```
  oDoc.Footnotes.Add Range:=oComment.Scope.Sentences(1).Characters.Last.Previous, Text:=oComment.Range.Text
```